# Shell scripting: Identify all the paths in a pattern

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to find the all the paths in a pattern and I am stuck. This is the structure of the directory

```
testdir
|-- dir with spaces
|    |-- subdir 
|    |    |
|    |    |-subfile.sh
|    |    
|    +-- 1.sh
|    |
|    +-- 2.sh
|
+-- dir1
|    |
|    |
|    +-- file.sh
|
+-- test.sh
```

this is the path pattern i have `testdir/**/*`

**What i want**

The output i am trying to get is

```
-flag testdir/dir\ with\ spaces/1.sh 
-flag testdir/dir\ with\ spaces/2.sh 
-flag testdir/dir\ with\ spaces/subdir 
-flag testdir/dir\ with\ spaces/subdir/subfile.sh
-flag testdir/dir1
-flag testdir/dir1/file.sh
-flag testdir/test.sh
```

**What i tried**

```
pathpattern=testdir/**/*
echo $pathpattern
```

It prints the following

```
testdir/dir with spaces/1.sh testdir/dir with spaces/2.sh testdir/dir with spaces/subdir testdir/dir1/file.sh
```

1. I tried doing an echo of the path pattern but it didn't return everything.
2. I also dont know to handle entries that have a space. I tried looping through $pathpattern, but failed to differentiate between a new path and a path that has a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
printf -- "-flag %q\n" testdir/**/*
```

However, this looks like probably a very poor way to accomplish ... something. Without knowledge of the actual end goal, it's hard to suggest how to do it properly. Typically, you don't want to produce a variable or string containing file names (let alone commands) and if you do, you shoud probably be using an array instead. But perhaps you simply want

```
for file in testdir/**/*; do
    : ... something with "$file"
done
```

The array solution would look something like

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^ sh doesn't have arrays
array=($(printf " -test %q" testdir/**/*))
your --program --call ${array[@]} --more arguments
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond to this.  The first option to print gives me the error "printf: -f: invalid option".   I already tried the second option - it breaks the paths with spaces into two results.      To your question of why i need this -  I am trying to specify the exclude paths for one of the api we are using. The input spec uses path patterns to determine paths to be excluded.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the `printf` error; sorry about that.  Your description of how the `for` loop failed sounds like you failed to double-quote the loop variable inside the loop.

Comment: Something like `api --call --options $(printf -- " -flag %q") -more options` would perhaps save you from keeping the result in a variable, which is always pesky.  If you can't do this, again, I suggest using an array.  There is a FAQ about this; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050